# How to render a template in django from a different app using Class Based Views?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm feeling I shouldn’t be asking thins question because it seems too easy. But I can't find a solution in the django docs or here.

I want to render a template in my class based generic ListView, which is in the templates folder of a different app.

My folder structure:

```
my_website
   -app1
   -app2
   -mywebsite
      -templates
         -users
            -welcome_pages
               -welcome_user.html

   -app3
     -templates
        -mytemplate.html
        -mytemplate2.html
     -views.py
     -models.py
```

In my app3 I have a view that looks like this:

```
class VisualizationView(StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = ????
    model = Project

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print(self.get_template_names())
        context = super(VisualizationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.all()

        return context
```

So I can easily render a template now in `template_name` which is in my app3 and spit out all my project objects there. But I want to render the context in welcome_user.html.

Normally the documentation says I should use `appname/templatename` but I get a TemplateDoesntExist Exception. I tried passing to template_name:

```
mywebsite/welcome_user.html
mywebsite/users/welcome_pages/welcome_user.html
welcome_user.html
mywebsite/templates/users/welcome_pages/welcome_user.html
```

If I print out `self.get_template_names()` I only get a list of templates that are within app3. I thought django would automatically be looking in the whole project wherever a template folder is? What am I missing here? Or is this not supposed to work in a CBV?

Apologies if this is a too easy question and thanks for any help. Appreciated !

Comment: What about `users/welcome_pages/welcome_user.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the template is located in a different app does not make any difference. The template folders are searched. So it means you can acces the template with:

```
class VisualizationView(StaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'users/welcome_pages/welcome_user.html'
    model = Project

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        print(self.get_template_names())
        context = super(VisualizationView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.all()

        return context
```

If you have set the [**`APP_DIRS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATES-APP_DIRS) to `True`, it will thus search the template directories of the apps, and eventually find a `users/` directory in the `template/` directory of your `users/` app, and find the relevant template.

Comment: uff that I haven't tried that.... Thank you very much @Willem! Saved me :)